# using `ViewChild` - method is not calling the child method

Tags: angular

I am trying to call my child components method from the parent, but not works at all.

here is my code :

```
<router-outlet>
   <app-modal-popup></app-modal-popup> //children for all pages!!
</router-outlet>
```

In the home page:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Output, ViewChild, AfterViewInit  } from '@angular/core';
    import { ModalPopupComponent } from '../../shared/modal/modal-popup/modal-popup.component';

    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

        @ViewChild('appModal') private appModal : ModalPopupComponent;

    footerLinkHandler(link){
        console.log('link', link );
        this.appModal.popMessage(link);
        return false;
    }

}
```

but getting an error as `Cannot read property 'popMessage' of undefined` - what is the issue. But i am getting the `popMessage` from `appModal` as auto filled.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Component({
 ...
directives: [ModalPopupComponent]
})

class HomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
 @ViewChild(ModalPopupComponent) childComp:ModalPopupComponent;
 ...
 footerLinkHandler(link){
    console.log('link', link );
    this.childComp.popMessage(link);
    return false;
 }
```